# How Can I identify Multiple Classes in One Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I want to remove my group chat messages via long click and delete button. But I cant remove the value of messages. Because in chatadapter I have only identified chat.class I need group.class because when I want to get reference from Firebase database I can't describe the path of messages. I need to identify group.class in chatadapter.
My firebase path:

```
Firebasereference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Groups").child(groupId).("Messages").child(timestamp);
```

My path is GROUPS=>GROUIPID(timestamp)=>MESSAGES=>TIMESTAMP OF USER

Comment: Why not create another String variable in Chat class & assign the Group Id to it?

Comment: Thanks I have already solved my issue. But How Can I read messages from where I am staying? (For new messages)